# Are there any issues with changing Java Integer to int?

Tags: java, integer

I recently inherited a bunch of code that uses Java Integer, for which I am getting a lot of compiler warnings.  I would like to convert these to int to eliminate the warnings (rather than suppress them).  My question is...are there any issues with simply changing Integer declarations to int?  Naturally I will test the code changes, but want to know ahead of time if I will be facing any issues.  I am using Java version 17.

Comment: Note that `Integer` is a type of object, while `int` is not, so if any of the code relies on one of these things being an object, that might cause an issue.

Comment: Another issue is serialization. `int` is program language neutral, whereas Integer is Java only. Objects are also much larger in memory than primatives

Comment: Another issue (in the realm of memory management) is that primitives that are not encapsulated as part of an object exist only on the stack, whereas Objects are all on the heap.

Comment: Your Question could be improved by posting the actual text of your compiler warnings.

Comment: If you have collectiosn like lists, that would be an issue..

Answer (score 1):

Very Yes. Integer can be null that can lead to null pointer exception. So do check before you convert to int